# PostgreSQL Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.0

I cannot connect to PostgreSQL server from PgAdmin III , so I get this error:

> Error connecting to the server:  server closed the connection
> unexpectedly
>
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while
> processing the request.

I get the same error when I try connecting from `psql`.

I have got this error 2 days ago but after restarting the computer the problem disappears , but this time I have restarted it too many times vainly.

I'm using PostgreSQL  9.0.5 on windows 7 with ArcSDE 10.1 (Arcgis Spatial Database add-on), I have deactivated the antivirus and firewall.

I have tried to reinstall PgSQL but the problem persists.

How I can connect to my Pgsql service and get rid of this error?

Comment: Please put the information in the comment into the question! Also, are you running Linux or Windows (or other)? What does `ps -ef | grep post` show (or Windows equivalent) show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like broken data file or broken indexes. If this problem grows, then it can shows some deep system problems - problems with hw (memory, CPU), os (antivirus)... Try to use a commands executed from command prompt for database access repairing a) reindexdb - refresh all indexes, b) pg_dump - recheck a readability of data files.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to do a) and b)?

Comment: @smwikipedia - look on SQL command REINDEX and shell command pg_dump or pg_dumpall

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when the postgres service is [not configured to listen on the address from which you are attempting your client connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9764126/4709762). This may be the case if you can connect to the service from some hosts, but receive this error message from others.

**If you are able to connect to the service from another host**, inspect the running configuration value of [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS).

```sql
show listen_addresses;

select * 
from pg_settings
where name = 'listen_addresses';
```

In short: a configuration value of `*` will allow the service to listen on all addresses. If you see another value (such as `localhost`, a hostname, or an IP address), then you may wish to add a record. You can do so by adding a comma and then your addresses to the `listen_addresses` line of [postgresql.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602450/4709762) and restarting the service. Note that if you add an IP address [it cannot be a CIDR range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125501/4709762)

See also: posts on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32844640/4709762), [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/336289/401889)