# PostgreSQL 9.4 : server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql

I have a website in production with low traffic (10-20 rpm). The application servers runs on the same box as the database, connection to the DB is done via localhost

For a few months everything has been running fine.

About 5 days ago Postgres started to randomly returns this error, about 1 error every 100 reqs :

> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>   This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

No major modification was done to the app, database or system setup.

If i understand the error message correctly, it means the database process was killed ?

I'm trying to understand what can cause this error :

- Postgres logs don't show anything (no log around error time)
- Kernel logs don't show anything either (no log around error time)
- Syslog only shows that a cron jobs started the requests that failed with this error

Memory usage on the server seems ok (70%), i have plenty of free disk space.

When i manually connect to Postgres through psql or the ruby PG client i can execute select and update queries.

I already had a look at this question :
[PostgreSQL Error : server closed the connection unexpectedly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54571/postgresql-error-server-closed-the-connection-unexpectedly)

I tried to re-index the tables. I also performed a pgdump which worked fine (i didn't restore data)

Environment :

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Postgres 9.4
- Database size is about 6.5GB

App connecting to the DB :

- Ruby on Rails 4.2
- PG gem 0.18.2

Comment: If  [auditd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/auditd.8.html) is active (otherwise activate it), does `ausearch -m ANOM_ABEND -ui postgres` report the abnormal terminations ? If yes, arrange to get [core dumps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/core.5.html)

Comment: As recommended on the link you provide, doing a restore might really be a good thing. If possible, provide the settings you modified in your postgresql.conf and maybe /etc/sysctl,conf (if any).

Comment: @vdaudry - I know its been 2 years, but did you figure out the issue?